# repeat horizontally splitted sprite to the left

Tags: css

[image: Spritesheet]

I have this spritesheet and I have to repeat each column horizontally to the left for different backgrounds. How can I achieve this? I played arround with background-position, background-repeat and background-size but I can´t achieve the desired behaviour. Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I better you can create sprite **vertical** instead of **horizontal** .

**Like this :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save each color seperately and dynamically build your background according to what you need?

So just repeat the color you want repeated and then append the others on the sides if you want them.

Also: Please be more specific as to the effect you want to achieve.